# CruiseControl on 64bit Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, cruisecontrol

I am using Cruise Control on windows server 2008 and I faces next problem - when I am trying to send mail notification I got this error:

```
2012-01-03 12:25:24,821 [RemoteDelivery-1] ERROR Aspirin          - RemoteDelivery (RemoteDelivery-1).deliver(): 
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is: 
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: 530 SMTP authentication is required.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:804)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:320)
    at org.masukomi.aspirin.core.RemoteDelivery.deliver(RemoteDelivery.java:291)
    at org.masukomi.aspirin.core.RemoteDelivery.run(RemoteDelivery.java:586)
```

I also get following error, and I cannot connect to dashboard by browser.

```
012-01-03 12:15:23,946 [Timer-6  ] WARN  BuildLoopStatusReportTask - Failed to reach dashboard instance : http://localhost:8080/dashboard/buildloop/listener, either the dashboard has not started up or there is a network problem.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1115)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1832)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1590)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.report.BuildLoopStatusReportTask.run(BuildLoopStatusReportTask.java:90)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.report.BuildLoopStatusReportTask.run(BuildLoopStatusReportTask.java:75)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Before it I used the same configuration of CruiseControl on WinXP and it worked fine. but on win 2008 server I got these problems. Please, help.

SOLUTION:
Second issue is fixed by uninstalling java 7 and installing java 6.
First issue was caused by wrong smtphost and port.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP server you're trying to relay mail through requires authentication (sometimes referred to as SMTP AUTH) to send the message:

> 530 SMTP authentication is required

Either switch to a local SMTP server that doesn't require authentication, or configure Cruise Control with a username and password to authenticate with.